# How to save the whole ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

[image: ggplot]

Hi, I made a ggplot, the labels is in a mess and not valuable. How to only show the labels of the bars that the frequencies is larger than 2? And My lengend is very large, when I save the pic, it only saves a part of the plot, how to save the whole plot?

I'm using this code:

```
    ggplot(df,aes(x = factor(month.year.created,levels = level.order), y = n, fill = Trend.Terms.RFx, label = value)) +
  labs(x = "Time created", y = "Frequency") +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(1))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow = 5, byrow=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of showing just some labels with a standard dataset that you could apply to your own.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Reshaping data
df <- group_by(mpg, class) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

g <- ggplot(df, aes(class, n, fill = class)) +
  geom_col() +
  # How to show only labels of the bars that are larger than some threshold
  geom_text(
    data = ~ subset(., n > 20),
    aes(label = class, y = n + 2)
  )
g
```

[image]

With regards to the legend, you could choose to display only some labels.

```r
# Showing just some labels
g + scale_fill_discrete(
    limits = df$class,
    breaks = df$class[df$n > 20]
  )
```

[image]

Or you could choose to not display the legend at all, since the text labels appear to show the same information.

```r
# Disabling the legend
g + guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Would help to have representative data to reproduce your issue. Based on the image yous shared:

First - to make legend text smaller:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262572/10276092

```
theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10))
```

Next, to only show labels greater than 2

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39682325/10276092

```
geom_text(position=pd, aes(label=ifelse(y>=2, value, ""), y=0.5*value))
```